# Problems dividing multilevel data into folds for cross validation using the perry package

Tags: r, cross-validation, lme4, multilevel-analysis, glmm

I am trying to assess the performance of a generlaized linear mixed model I have built using behavior and performance data from dairy cows. The data has a nested structure (cows within farms) which I have  tried to reflect in the model.

I would like to evaluate the model accuracy using 10-k cross validation. I understand that in this case it would be correct to separate the train/test folds according to the animal identification in order not to leak information from the individual into the fold for model validation.

I have a dataset with roughly 39k observations and each observation in the dataset (sample.all2.smote2) has daily values for each behavioral and performance parameters for a specific animal (BTN1). An example of some of the (centered and scaled) variables with the animal identification (BTN1) and the ouctome variable (lame3) looks like such:

```
structure(list(C.FDM = structure(c(-1.34812143299885, 0.325019476478028, 
0.325019476478028, 0.325019476478028, -1.14871001333241, -0.918179588196105, 
-0.972579804858759, -0.966815543490536, -0.966815543490536, -0.966815543490536
), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), C.MN = structure(c(2.55666426898236, -0.409093516437576, 
-0.409093516437576, -0.409093516437576, 2.01743558072419, 1.47820689246602, 
0.669363860078765, 0.669363860078765, 0.669363860078765, 0.669363860078765
), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), C.MNR = structure(c(-1.83758883987204, 
0.580129190951948, 0.580129190951948, 0.580129190951948, 0.170346473863136, 
-0.0857677243173708, -0.0503057584154545, -0.0503057584154545, 
-0.0503057584154545, -0.0503057584154545), .Dim = c(10L, 1L)), 
    DIM = structure(c(-0.958148248887972, -0.940237880247739, 
    -0.940237880247739, -0.940237880247739, -0.904417142967273, 
    -0.88650677432704, -0.877551590006924, -0.850686037046574, 
    -0.850686037046574, -0.850686037046574), .Dim = c(10L, 1L
    )), lame3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), BTN1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
    "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
    "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
    "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
    "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
    "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", 
    "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", 
    "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
    "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
    "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
    "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
    "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
    "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
    "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
    "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
    "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
    "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
    "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
    "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have found a code that works well for 10-k cross validation, except I can't get around a problem with the folds and the grouping.

I adapted this code (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/241926_6490553c521743529a1d64607be948c3.html) to my data/model and it now looks like this:

```
library (perry)
library (dplyr)
library (lme4)
library (epiR)
library (caret)
library (pROC)

fold_cv=function(data,k){
  folds= perry::cvFolds(nrow(data),K=k, grouping = droplevels(sample.all2.smote2$BTN1))
  invisible(folds)
}

fold3<-sample.all2.smote2%>%fold_cv(., k = 10)
str(fold3)


######

temp<-sample.all2.smote2%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Fold = rep(0,nrow(sample.all2.smote2)),holdoutpred=rep(0,nrow(sample.all2.smote2)),
         MSE=rep(0,nrow(.)),RMSE=rep(0,nrow(.)),MAE=rep(0,nrow(.)),
         AIC=rep(0,nrow(.)),ROC=rep(0,nrow(.)), sen=rep(0,nrow(.)),
         spec=rep(0,nrow(.))) 

temp$lame3<-as.numeric(as.character(temp$lame3))

for(i in 1:10){
  train=temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which != i], ]
  validation=temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]
  newlm=lme4::glmer(formula=lame3 ~  C.MN + DIM (DIM | BTN1), 
                    family = binomial(link = logit),
                    data = train, 
                    na.action = "na.fail", nAGQ = 0,
                    control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1e6)))
  newpred=predict(newlm,newdata=validation, type="response")
  true=validation$lame3
  type="response"
  error=(true-newpred)
  rmse=sqrt(mean(error^2))
  mse=mean((newpred-true)^2)
  mae=mean(abs(error))
  coordsbest = ROC %>%
    coords("best")
  threshold = coordsbest[1,1]
  ROC=roc(true, newpred)
  preds = ifelse (newpred >= threshold, 1, 0)
  conf.matrix = confusionMatrix(as.factor(preds), as.factor(true), positive = "1")
  conf.matrix$table<-conf.matrix$table[c(2,1),c(2,1)]
  epi.test = epi.tests(conf.matrix$table)
  
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$holdoutpred <- newpred
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$RMSE=rmse
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$MSE=mse
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$MAE=mae
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$ROC=as.numeric(ROC$auc)
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$sen=epi.test$elements$se
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$spec=epi.test$elements$sp
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$AIC=AIC(newlm)
  temp[fold3$subsets[fold3$which == i], ]$Fold=i
}
```

This code gives me results, but I noticed many of the metrics were 0, so I looked further and saw that the cvFolds function was randomly assinging fold numbers only to 190 observations (the number of individual BTN1s), the rest were left as Fold = 0.
If I leave out the grouping argument from perry::cvFolds all observations get assigned to a fold.

How can i get the function to assign a Fold to each obsbervation and respect the grouping given by BTN1 at the same time?

Comment: Is your code supposed to have these backlashes (``\``)?

Comment: I haven't tried to dig into this (and might not have time to), but have you considered trying out the `tidymodels` framework for this? https://www.tidymodels.org/ ... the `multilevelmod` package lets you work with (G)LMMs in a "tidymodel" context, and its possible that the machinery for stratified/blocked CV is more robust/better documented there ?

Comment: @jrcalabrese - it wasn't! Thanks for pointing that out!